# Excel ttest subtract cells from formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am performing a two tailed ttest on two data incomplete data sets.  There is an `x` in the cells with no data.  Can I work the formula to analyze eg. B24:DZ24 but subtract any cell with containing an `x`?

**Current formula:**

```
=ttest(d24:dz24,d25:dc25,2,2)
```

Comment: Doesn't it error out on non-numeric values? TTest also ignore any 'false' conditions, so you can work an `if` in somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

Best to put in an extra step that makes new ranges containing only numbers. If you're comfortable with VBA you could fake it with a user-defined function by using never-used ranges (like right-most or bottom-most), populating them with code that removes the "x"s, passing them to `worksheetfunction.ttest(theNewRange1, theNewRange2,2,2)`, setting the cell you want to that value, then cleaning up by clearing the temporary ranges (so they can be used over and over).

But that is hacky and difficult to remember 3 months down the road. I think the better solution is to have sheets that use the "x"s if you need 'em; and another sheet (or just other ranges on the same sheet/tab) without the "x"s.